# Shema in Pesukei D'zimra

Tags: shema, bircas-krias-shema

When one says Shema in korbanot, is he yotzei in the mitzvah of Kriyat Shema?

Its best to say shema with its brachot; however, if one were to fulfill the mitzvah of Shema by saying the verse in Pesukei D'zimra, he would be doing it without the brachot. Therefore, should one skip this verse if he or she is going to daven shema, with its brachot, in time?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95_%D7%98 every opinion you could imagine is on the books

Comment: @Dov in the Rema there: "וטוב לומר בשחרית אחר שמע ישראל וגו' ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד, כי לפעמים שוהין עם קריאת שמע לקרותה שלא בזמנה ויוצא בזה (טור)"

Answer (score 1):

According to the Vilna Gaon (Maaseh Rav 11), one should indeed say only "Pa'amayim bechol yom: Shema Yisrael." OR "Pa'amayim bechol yom: H' Elokeinu H' echad" at this place. The reason is explained in Beur HaGRA O"Ch 46:19. Rav Sa'adya of Shklov writes that the Gaon's custom was to say "Pa'amayim bechol yom H' Elokeinu H' echad".

As always, others disagree.

Comment: This is a pretty extreme position, because not only does it think saying shema without it's blessings is problematic, it also thinks that one can accidentally fulfill their obligation by saying the first verse without baruch shem and without intention to fulfill an obligation.

Comment: The first part (shema without brachos) is discussed by rishonim (see the Beur HaGra above and Beur Halacha there). The second part (kavanah) indeed needs explanation and Rav Seraya Divlitzky in Zeh Hashulchan states that a negative kavanah (i.e. davka not to be yotze) would work even according the GRA, he just did not want to really on it.

Comment: I know, I'm just pointing out that from the very wide range of opinions that exist here you picked to only present the most extreme in all ways.